# 拡張子が「css」or「js」または、文字列中に「/test/」を含んであるものにマッチする正規表現

Tags: java, 正規表現

拡張子が「css」or「js」または、文字列中に「/test/」を含んであるものにマッチする正規表現の書き方が分かりません。

また、現在の状態は下記になりますが、コンパイルエラーとなっています

```html
文字列.matches("*\.[css|js]|*/test/*")
```

Comment: まず、文字列中のエスケープ文字はエスケープする必要があります。

Comment: おそらく`"\\.(css|js)$|.*/test/.*"`のような感じ（未テスト）？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。エスケープを怠っていました。参考に見直してみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
.*\\.(css|js)+$|.*/test/.*
```

上記で実現することが出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

```
\.(css|js)$|/test/
```

これではダメですかね？

---

`*`は前の文字を0回以上繰り返すって意味なので、単独で書いてはダメですね。`*`の前に対象となる文字が無いと...
ワイルドカードと混同してしまってませんか？

Comment: ワイルドカードと混同していました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。